# GroupLayout Error: can't find wrong line

Tags: java, swing, illegalstateexception

```
package edu.uga.cs1302.gui;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import javax.swing.*;


public class StudentDirectory extends JFrame implements ActionListener{

private static final long serialVersionUID = 3294408483853747952L;
private Student current;
private ArrayList<Student> data;
private ArrayList<Student> unsavedData;
private ObjectOutputStream oos;
private FileOutputStream fos;


    public StudentDirectory() throws FileNotFoundException{
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Student Directory");

    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setVisible(true);
    frame.setSize(300,300);

    data = new ArrayList<Student>();
    unsavedData = new ArrayList<Student>();
    current = new Student();
    unsavedData.add(current);
    try {
        fos = new FileOutputStream("StudentsList.dat");
        oos = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);
    } catch (IOException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }

    JMenuBar mb = new JMenuBar();
    JMenu file = new JMenu("File");
    JMenuItem load = new JMenuItem("Load");
    JMenuItem save = new JMenuItem("Save");
    JMenuItem exit = new JMenuItem("Exit");

    file.add(load);
    file.add(save);
    file.addSeparator();
    file.add(exit);
    mb.add(file);
    frame.setJMenuBar(mb);

    JPanel Pane = (JPanel) frame.getContentPane();
    GroupLayout layout = new GroupLayout(Pane);
    Pane.setLayout(layout);
    layout.setAutoCreateGaps(true);
    layout.setAutoCreateContainerGaps(true);

    JLabel ID = new JLabel("ID:");
    JTextField IDn = new JTextField();
    IDn.setEditable(true);

    JLabel first = new JLabel("First Name:");
    JTextField firstN = new JTextField();
    firstN.setEditable(true);

    JLabel last = new JLabel("Last Name:");
    JTextField lastN = new JTextField();
    lastN.setEditable(true);

    JLabel DOB = new JLabel("Date of Birth:");
    JTextField dateN = new JTextField();
    dateN.setEditable(true);

    JLabel college = new JLabel("College:");
    JTextField collegeN = new JTextField();
    collegeN.setEditable(true);

    JButton prev = new JButton("Previous");
    JButton next = new JButton("Next");
    JButton append = new JButton("Append");

    prev.setEnabled(false);

    layout.setHorizontalGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING)
                .addComponent(ID)
                .addComponent(first)
                .addComponent(last)
                .addComponent(DOB)
                .addComponent(college)
                .addComponent(prev))
            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                .addComponent(IDn)
                .addComponent(firstN)
                .addComponent(lastN)
                .addComponent(dateN)
                .addComponent(collegeN)
                .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addComponent(next)
                        .addComponent(append))
                )
            );

    layout.setVerticalGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(ID)
                    .addComponent(IDn))
            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(first)
                    .addComponent(firstN))
            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(last)
                    .addComponent(lastN))
            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(DOB)
                    .addComponent(dateN))
            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(college)
                    .addComponent(collegeN))
            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(prev)
                    .addComponent(next)
                    .addComponent(append))
        );

        exit.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                dispose();
                System.exit(0);
            }
          }
        );
        load.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
                try {
                    fos = new FileOutputStream("StudentsList.dat");
                    oos.reset();
                    for(int i = 0; i < data.size();i++){
                        oos.writeObject(data.get(i));
                    }
                } catch (IOException e1) {
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
        });

        save.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
                try {
                    oos.flush();
                    oos.close();
                } catch (IOException e1) {
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });

        IDn.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                int index = unsavedData.indexOf(current);
                unsavedData.remove(index);
                String num = IDn.getText();
                int idInput = Integer.parseInt(num);
                current.setID(idInput);
                unsavedData.add(index, current);

            }

        });

        firstN.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                int index = unsavedData.indexOf(current);
                unsavedData.remove(index);
                String currentFirst = firstN.getText();
                current.setFirst(currentFirst);
                unsavedData.add(index, current);
            }
        });

        lastN.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                int index = unsavedData.indexOf(current);
                unsavedData.remove(index);
                String currentLast = lastN.getText();
                current.setLast(currentLast);
                unsavedData.add(index, current);
            }
        });

        dateN.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                int index = unsavedData.indexOf(current);
                unsavedData.remove(index);
                String currentDOB = dateN.getText();
                try {
                    current.setDOB(currentDOB);
                } catch (ParseException e1) {
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }
                unsavedData.add(index, current);
            }
        });

        collegeN.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                int index = unsavedData.indexOf(current);
                unsavedData.remove(index);
                String currentCollege = collegeN.getText();
                current.setCollege(currentCollege);
                unsavedData.add(index, current);
            }
        });

        prev.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
                int index = unsavedData.indexOf(current);
                if(index!=0)
                    if(index-1==0){
                        prev.setEnabled(false);
                    }
                    current= unsavedData.get(index-1);
                    IDn.cut();
                    IDn.setText(""+current.getID());
                    firstN.cut();
                    firstN.setText(current.getFirst());
                    lastN.cut();
                    lastN.setText(current.getLast());
                    dateN.cut();
                    dateN.setText(current.getDOB());
                    collegeN.cut();
                    collegeN.setText(current.getCollege());
            }

        });

        next.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                prev.setEnabled(true);
                int index = unsavedData.indexOf(current);
                if(index+1< unsavedData.size()){
                    current = unsavedData.get(index+1);
                    IDn.cut();
                    IDn.setText(""+current.getID());
                    firstN.cut();
                    firstN.setText(current.getFirst());
                    lastN.cut();
                    lastN.setText(current.getLast());
                    dateN.cut();
                    dateN.setText(current.getDOB());
                    collegeN.setText(current.getCollege());
                }else{
                    current = new Student();
                    IDn.setText("");
                    firstN.setText("");
                    lastN.setText("");
                    dateN.setText("");
                    collegeN.setText("");
                    unsavedData.add(current);
                }
                index++;
            }
        });

        append.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                data = new ArrayList<Student>();
                for(int x = 0;x<unsavedData.size();x++){
                    data.add(unsavedData.get(x));
                }
            }
        });



        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.validate();


}
@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
}
```

main method

```
package edu.uga.cs1302.gui;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class StudentMain {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException{
        new StudentDirectory();
    }
}
```

My error happens when I use the Prev Button.

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.IllegalStateException: javax.swing.JTextField[,0,0,0x0,invalid,layout=javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicTextUI$UpdateHandler,alignmentX=0.0,alignmentY=0.0,border=com.apple.laf.AquaTextFieldBorder@154fd2c3,flags=288,maximumSize=,minimumSize=,preferredSize=,caretColor=javax.swing.plaf.ColorUIResource[r=0,g=0,b=0],disabledTextColor=javax.swing.plaf.ColorUIResource[r=128,g=128,b=128],editable=true,margin=javax.swing.plaf.InsetsUIResource[top=0,left=0,bottom=0,right=0],selectedTextColor=com.apple.laf.AquaImageFactory$SystemColorProxy[r=0,g=0,b=0],selectionColor=com.apple.laf.AquaImageFactory$SystemColorProxy[r=164,g=205,b=255],columns=0,columnWidth=0,command=,horizontalAlignment=LEADING] is not attached to a vertical group
    at javax.swing.GroupLayout.checkComponents(GroupLayout.java:1090)
    at javax.swing.GroupLayout.prepare(GroupLayout.java:1040)
    at javax.swing.GroupLayout.layoutContainer(GroupLayout.java:910)
    at java.awt.Container.layout(Container.java:1510)
    at java.awt.Container.doLayout(Container.java:1499)
    at java.awt.Container.validateTree(Container.java:1695)
    at java.awt.Container.validateTree(Container.java:1704)
    at java.awt.Container.validateTree(Container.java:1704)
    at java.awt.Container.validate(Container.java:1630)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager$3.run(RepaintManager.java:711)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager$3.run(RepaintManager.java:709)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager.validateInvalidComponents(RepaintManager.java:708)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager$ProcessingRunnable.run(RepaintManager.java:1731)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:311)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:756)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:726)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
    at     java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.util.Calendar.setTime(Calendar.java:1770)
    at java.text.SimpleDateFormat.format(SimpleDateFormat.java:943)
    at java.text.SimpleDateFormat.format(SimpleDateFormat.java:936)
    at java.text.DateFormat.format(DateFormat.java:345)
    at edu.uga.cs1302.gui.Person.getDOB(Person.java:50)
    at edu.uga.cs1302.gui.StudentDirectory$9.actionPerformed(StudentDirectory.java:234)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2022)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2348)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6535)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3324)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6300)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2236)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4891)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2294)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4713)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4888)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4525)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4466)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2280)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2750)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4713)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:758)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:86)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:731)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:729)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:728)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
```

My Student class has several parameters (String firstname, String lastname, String Date, String college, int ID)

the Date is converted to a Date w Simple Date Format(MM-dd-yyyy) in constructor (might be one of the errors)

the point of my code: should load an ArrayList of Students into memory. Should show the information of the first Student of the ArrayList w GUI.  Information exported to a "StudentsList.dat" file. Saved to file when "Append" button is clicked.
"File" menu with three menu-items: "Load", "Save", "Exit".
"Load" loads the ArrayList of Students from the above file into memory.
"Save" saves the ArrayList of Students into the above file.
"Exit" terminates the program.
The "Previous" button goes back to the preceding Student in the ArrayList. This button should be disabled if we are at the beginning of the ArrayList.
The "Next" button shows the succeeding Student in the ArrayList. This button should be disabled if we are at the end of the ArrayList.

Comment: The [IllegalStateException API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/IllegalStateException.html) states that it is called when *"a method has been invoked at an illegal or inappropriate time"*. If this were my problem, I'd first make sure that my GUI was started on the Swing event thread. Do you do that? Create a Runnable and queue it into the event thread via `SwingUtilities.invokeLater(...)`?

Comment: hm so in my constructor use the command SwingUtilities.invokeLater()? Not quite sure what you mean by that

Comment: Often the static method call above is done within the main method or wherever you create the GUI. Post how you create your GUI, perhaps your main method.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels this is my full code

Comment: So.... was that the problem?

Comment: no! the JTextFields didn't need action listeners. I just used example.getText() in the prev and next method. so the problem is solved @HovercraftFullOfEels

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Again, what I'm suggesting is that you call your GUI from the Swing event thread as per Swing documentation recommendations. For example:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> {
        // this is inside a "lambda" Runnable
        try {
            new StudentDirectory();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    });
}
```